# Unintended behavior from boost::operators

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I'm taking `boost::operators` (clang 2.1, boost 1.48.0) for a spin, and ran into the following behavior I can't explain. It seems that when I add my own `operator double() const` method to my class `Ex` (as I'd like to allow my users to idiomatically use `static_cast<double>()` on instances of my class), I no longer get a compiler error when trying to use `operator==` between dissimilar classes. In fact, it seems that `operator==` is not called at all.

Without `operator double() const`, the class works completely as expected (save for that it now lacks a conversion operator), and I receive the correct complier error when trying `f == h`.

So what is the right way to add this conversion operator? Code below.

```
// clang++ -std=c++0x boost-operators-example.cpp -Wall -o ex  
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T, int N>
class Ex : boost::operators<Ex<T,N>> {
 public:
  Ex(T data) : data_(data) {};
  Ex& operator=(const Ex& rhs) {
    data_ = rhs.data_;
    return *this;
  };
  T get() {
    return data_ * N;
  };
  // the troubling operator double()
  operator double() const {
    return double(data_) / N;
  };
  bool operator<(const Ex& rhs) const {
    return data_ < rhs.data_;
  };
  bool operator==(const Ex& rhs) const {
    return data_ == rhs.data_;
  };
 private:
  T data_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Ex<int,4> f(1);
  Ex<int,4> g(2);
  Ex<int,2> h(1);

  // this will fail for obvious reasons when operator double() is not defined
  //
  // error: cannot convert 'Ex<int, 4>' to 'double' without a conversion operator

  std::cout << static_cast<double>(f) << '\n';


  std::cout 
    // ok
    << (f == g) 

    // this is the error I'm supposed to get, but does not occur when I have
    // operator double() defined 
    //
    // error: invalid operands to binary expression 
    //  ('Ex<int, 4>' and 'Ex<int, 2>')
    // note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 
    //  'Ex<int, 2>' to 'const Ex<int, 4>' for 1st argument
    //   bool operator==(const Ex& rhs) const 
    << (f == h)  
    << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should mark your `operator double()` as explicit. That allows the static cast, but prevents it being used as an implicit conversion when you test for equality (and in other cases).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you explain in a bit more detail on how the compiler thought an equality test merited an implicit conversion?

Comment: When the compiler does overload resolution it includes the built in operators - including `operator ==(double, double)`. And it's allowed to use one implicit conversion for each argument, so that one is a valid candidate. And there's no better alternative so it is chosen.

Comment: The thing about implicit conversions (conversion operators and constructors) is that they're implicit. By having one you're pretty much saying that your type is equivalent to a double. This is useful when you need it, but normally it's best to keep conversions explicit.